# Anadir columna a un scaffold Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

soy principiante en Ruby y tengo la siguiente pregunta:
tras haber generado un scaffold llamado negociaciones con los campos nombre:string apellidos:string me he dado cuenta de que me falta uno más, edad:integer. He intentado generarlo manualmente y luego he corrido rake db:migrate. Sin embargo no me lo coje. Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya ejecutaste las migraciones y quieres agregar la columna, puedes hacerlo mediante otra migración; por ejemplo:

```
rails generate migration AddEdadToNegociaciones edad:integer
```

Lo que generará una nueva migración con el siguiente contenido:

```
class AddEdadToNegocaciones < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :negocaciones, :edad, :integer
  end
end
```

Ahora únicamente debes ejecutar tus migraciones nuevamente:

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

---

Si no quieres generar una nueva migración y prefieres actualizar la generada por el *scaffold*, puedes hacerlo pero tendrás primero que hacer un *rollback* para que pueda detectar el cambio:

```
$ rails db:rollback
```

Después del *rollback* actualiza la migración:

```
class CreateNegociaciones < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :negociaciones do |t|
      t.string :nombre
      t.string :apellidos
      t.integer :edad

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Y, finalmente, ejecuta nuevamente las migraciones:

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

Comment: Disculpa  Gerry que te conteste un poco tarde. Quería darte las gracias. Efectivamente así ha funcionado. Saludos

Comment: @user87071 Súper! Me da gusto haber ayudado. Por favor no olvides aceptar la respuesta (dando clic a la paloma). Suerte!

Comment: perdona, y donde está la paloma? estoy viendo donde encontrar "aceptar la respuesta" pero no lo veo...

Comment: @user87071 Está en la columna izquierda de mi respuesta, abajo del número que tiene dos flechas (una apuntando arriba y otra abajo).

Comment: estupendo, hecho!